# Haxe Interface that extends Iterable

Tags: generics, interface, haxe

I have an interface that extends Iterable (as well as other interfaces).

```
interface MyInterface extends Iterable {
  public function iterator ():Iterator<Dynamic>;
}
```

this gives me

> MyInterface.hx:1: lines 1-3 : Invalid number of type parameters for
>   Iterable

what is the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Iterable`](https://api.haxe.org/Iterable.html?) is defined as a [`typedef`](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-typedef.html), not an `interface`, so this can't work.

Simply adding a function named `iterator()` to your class will do the trick, no need to implement or extend anything. This mechanism is called [structural subtyping](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-structural-subtyping.html).

There's more information about Iterators [here](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-iterators.html).